# Finding a specific element in a xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have multiple xml files to be processed and written into a single xml file. I have done most of the transformation and struck at one place of finding a specific element in one xml file.

One of the source xml is (parts.xml):

```
<parts>
    <part>
        <name>head shaft</name>
        <code>100</code>
    </part>
    ...
</parts>
```

Another source xml (price.xml):

```
<price-list>
    <price>
        <part-name>head shaft</part-name>
        <cost>28.45</cost>
        ...
    </price>
    ...
</price-list>
```

And I have to fetch only the code element belonging to a specific name element. 
This is only one source xml file, like this I have many to be processed.

My output xml has to be like this (result.xml):

```
<part-order>
    <part code=100 name="head shaft" price=32.05 qty=1 />
    ...
</part-order>
```

My xslt function to fetch part code is:

```
<xsl:function name="p:find">
    <xsl:variable name="partdoc" select="document('parts.xml')"/>
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$partdoc/p:/parts/part[contains(p:name,  '$str')]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$partdoc/p:code" />
</xsl:function>
```

And finally, I want to call the function like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="code">
            <xsl:value-of select="p:find('head shaft')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <part code="{'$code'}" name="{'head shaft'}" price="{$somelogic}"/>                     
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Its not working since I am making some mistake at the function declaration. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a key `<xsl:key name="part-ref" match="parts/part" use="name"/>` and then use a global param or variable `<xsl:variable name="partdoc" select="document('parts.xml')"/>`, then you can use `<part code="{key('part-ref', 'head shaft', $partdoc)/code}" .../>`.

There is no need to write a function for cross-references as keys provide thatt.

Here is a complete example, the primary input document is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<price-list>
    <price>
        <part-name>head shaft</part-name>
        <cost>28.45</cost>
        ...
    </price>
    ...
</price-list>
```

the other document is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parts>
    <part>
        <name>head shaft</name>
        <code>100</code>
    </part>
    ...
</parts>
```

given the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="part-ref" match="parts/part" use="name"/>

    <xsl:variable name="partdoc" select="document('parts.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="price-list">
        <part-order>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </part-order>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="price">
        <part code="{key('part-ref', part-name, $partdoc)/code}" name="{part-name}" price="{cost}" qty="1" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
<part-order>
    <part code="100" name="head shaft" price="28.45" qty="1"/>
    ...
</part-order>
```

Comment: Is calling the document reference in key possible? When I tried to call it, its not displaying any result. key('part-ref', 'head shaft', $partdoc)/code

Comment: @SrikrishnaPothukuchi, I have edited the answer with a full example that works fine for me. If you still have problems then edit your question showing minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT you now have, output you get and information about the used XSLT processor.

Comment: Thanks a million Martin. As you rightly pointed out, it is problem with my Eclipse. I am using Saxon 9.7 with Eclipse Neon. Sometimes it is behaving incorrectly. When I used XML Spear, the same code is working with 100% accuracy.

Comment: Thanks again Martin. I incorporated the keys into main application and its working well. Best regards!